# get the value of a textbox from a nested movieclip in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I got an fla file with nested movieclips. The "username" text box is present in a movieclip "login" which is included in another movieclip "member".

How to access the value of the textbox "username" in actionscript when a button is clicked(on(release) event ). the button is also present in the "login" movieclip

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using AS2 here...

If your button and your textbox are siblings (ie both contained in the same parent clip), then you can use this code on your button:

```
on (release) {
  trace(this);// should be 'login'
  trace(this.username.text);// should be the content of username textbox
}
```

This assumes that your button is tracked as a button and not a movieclip, otherwise you could use `this._parent.username.text` to get the contents of the textbox.

Another way is to use absolute addressing, but this is *not recommended*, since it's easy to break: either `_level0.login.username.text` or `_root.login.username.text`

Hope this helps!